# PDF website crawler

Tags: open-source, pdf, download-manager, scraping

I need an open source system that can crawl websites to gather PDF documents and then index them.

Comment: What format should the index take? An HTML page? Something else? Should the app only look at document titles (and PDF extension), or also examine the contents?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [httrack](https://www.httrack.com/) to copy website data locally. I think you will be able to change the parameters of the httrack config and download the PDF only files as you have mentinoed here.